# Mapbox Popup with jQuery Content

Tags: jquery, mapbox, geojson

I spent the last two days trying to figure this out. But it turns out, I can't.
I have set up a map with mapbox and I have a GeoJSON file for my markers. The markers contain a title, description and so on. One new feature should be a display of the opening hours, I found a nice little jQuery Plugin which does the work for me and everything seems to work just fine but after testing it with more markers, it always shows the first openinghours record in the GeoJSON.

My Code (this is just the part where the magic should happen)

```
$.getJSON('assets/geojson/locations_dev.geojson', function (geojson) {
      geojson.features.forEach(function (marker) {

        // create a HTML element for each feature
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'marker';

        //Get Data for Opening Hours
        var data = marker.properties.openinghours;

        //Check if data is not empty
        if(data != null) {
          function currentStatus() {
            $('.current-status-placeholder').openingHours({ show: 'current-status', hours: data});
            $('span:contains("Geöffnet")').addClass('open');
            $('span:contains("Geschlossen")').addClass('closed');
          }

          function closingIn() {
            $('.closing-in-placeholder').openingHours({ show: 'closing-in', hours: data});
            $('span:contains("Öffnet")').addClass('closing-hint');
          }

          //Only allow one click on each marker and draw the current status
          $(document).one('click', '.marker', function() {
              currentStatus();
              closingIn();
          });
        }

        var content = '<span class="badge current-status-placeholder"></span><br><span class="closing-in-placeholder"></span><h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p><p>' + '<span class="product-title">Es gibt: </span>' + marker.properties.products + '</p><p>' + '<span class="product-title">Wie?: </span>' + marker.properties.how + '</p><p>' + '<span class="product-title">Telefon: </span><a href="tel:' + marker.properties.tele + '">'+ marker.properties.tele +'</a></p><p>' + '<a class="website" target="_blank" href="' + marker.properties.link + '">Website + Mehr</a></p>';

        // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
          .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
            .setHTML(content))
          .addTo(map);
      });
  });
```

I think it could be something with the `.one()` function. For my understanding, I thought this is happening for each marker since it is in the loop.

```
$(document).one('click', '.marker', function() {
              currentStatus();
              closingIn();
          });
```

For a better testing environment, you can view the code up and running here:
http://saveyourlocalwirtshaus.de/index_dev.html